# multiple Image objects into a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, image

If I've multiple Image objects created like so:

```
var img0 = new Image();
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
```

What is the easiest and/or fastest way to wrap these into a jQuery object?

My current approach seems suboptimal:

```
var imgsJq = $(img0).add( $(img1) ).add( $(img2) );
```

Comment: That would actually be the most appropriate way to do that, using add(), so it's fine, but `$(img0).add(img1).add(img2);` does seem easier.

Comment: Just create an object literal and reference it's properties within your jQuery code.  easier to read that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var imgsJq = $([img0, img1, img2]);
```

Comment: This works, but is'nt much different from using add(), still +1.

Comment: It is cleaner and probably faster than add(). You can improve it if you put your images in an array instead of in 3 variables, but it does not change too much. `var imgs = [new Image(), new Image(), new Image()], imgsJq = $(imgs);`

Answer (score 1):

yours' is fine perfectly but if you want you can use the following as it looks simpler

```
 var $img = $(img0).add(img1).add(img2);
```

or you can use this also

```
 var $img = $([img0,img1,img2]);
```